# Can't change a user's profile

Tags: profile, userlicense, user-profile

I have a method that changes a user's profile. It works well when the old and the new profiles belong to the same user licence, but when they're from different user licences, it throws an error.

Here's my code:

```
public static void changeProfile(ID userId, ID profileId){
    User u=[select id, name, contactid, profileId from User where id=:userId];
    Profile p=[select id, name from profile where id=:profileId];
    u.ProfileId=p.Id; 
    update u;
}
```

And this is the error:

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0051I000000aVQbQAM; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, You can only assign profiles that are compatible with the user's license. For a list of compatible licenses and profiles, see the Salesforce Help.: [ProfileId]

How can I solve this?

I'm working with communities, by the way, and the profiles that I'm working with belong to Customer Portal Manager Licence and Customer Community Licence.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199523&type=1

Comment: Ok, but that page is suggesting to create a new user every time I want to change the profile. Right now I'm using developer edition, so there should be no problem in creating as many users as I want, but I don't think that solution is very efficient, since the org will soon have a lot of inactive users. Is there no other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: The below answer is still mostly true, but there are exceptions. You can, for example, change a [Chatter user to a Salesforce user](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000322789&type=1) licence, but you cannot later downgrade that user back to a Chatter
user.

---

You can't change the user's license type after creation, therefore you cannot change their profile to a new license type than what they had at creation. This restriction is probably in place because changing the user's license type might cause orphan data or break other database constraints. For now, you need to create new users. And yes, you will have lots of inactive users, but they don't count against your license limits. Consider setting their usernames to nonsense values when you deactivate them so they don't conflict with real email addresses.

Comment: I am trying to automate our user administration. Is the editing of license type still not possible as far as you know? I can't seem to find any information on this besides this post.

Comment: @CornévanKlink I've added a relevant link. There are some types of changes you can make to a user, such as upgrading from Chatter Free to a Salesforce license, but you cannot later downgrade them back. Other exceptions may also exist, but I expect them to be rare.

Comment: @sfdcfox is it possible to change the licence from chatter free to salesforce via code or does it have to be done via the UI?

Comment: @StevenHodge The documentation doesn't say, so I'm not sure.